# How can we give separate color for the cells with event in a fullcalendar with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, sharepoint-2013

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
  var dateString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  $('#myCalendar').find('.fc-day-number[data-date=' + dateString + ']').css('background-color', 'skyblue');
}
```

I've used the following function but it only colors half the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
  var dateString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  $('#myCalendar').find('.fc-day .fc-day-number[data-date=' + dateString + ']').css('background-color', 'skyblue')
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. This code doesn't seem to work for me.